# Restore Data in FragmentActivity after back button Pressed

Tags: android-fragments, bundle, android-fragmentactivity, data-retrieval

I've read a lot of things about restoring data in FragmentActivity but nothing works in my case. I tried a lot of methods to do it but it never worked.

I have a FragmentActivity containing a ViewPager with 6 or 7 fragments. These fragments are containing each one a ListView. The datas in these ListView have been retrieved from web.

I can select an item of the ListView in a fragment to open an new activity showing the detail of the selected item.

When i go back to my FragmentActivity i don't want to retrieve a new time datas from web, but getting it from a bundle or whatever allowing me to display data instantly.

I tried getLast(Custom)NonconfigurationInstance() but it is only called when a real configuration has been changed (such as screen orientation). I also tried onSavedInstanceState  in FragmentActivity, in Fragment, whith and without calling the super method... I always get a null savedInstanceState bundle in my onCreate/onCreateView.

I don't have piece of code for you because i go back to zero.

Any ideas please ?

Comment: Save the data in a persistent way(preferences, file, database) when you first get it.

Comment: I thought about it but I think it's a bad practice : the Preferences should be used to save persistent data ; even when the application is closed, the data are persistent. but i haven't another way to do that  for now so i will try this.

Comment: Or you could save it at the Application level and keep it in memory as long as the Application exists. When you come back to that `Activity` see if you have the data available(maybe with a timestamp to see if you shouldn't refresh it even if it exists) and if it isn't available retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found a solution but i hate it ! anyway...

When i select an item in the list of my fragment, i put the data i want to restore in the ActivityA with a custom Class that implements Serializable, and i close ActivityA. ActivityB is launching. when i close ActivityB, i put the data iwant to restore in ActivityA. I check if my data are not null (it can be null if i don't come from ActivityB), and if they aren't, i can populate my fragments and my lists without network connection.

It's a very bad way to solve my problem, but i have really no idea why the "savedInstanceState" methods are not working in this case.